FIWARE Unauthorized Errors: "Domain not Found" with OAuth2 and "User not Authorized in the Application" with /v1/auth/tokens
I am setting up a FIWARE platform using Docker Compose to manage IoT devices. The setup includes the Orion Context Broker, IoT Agent, and Keyrock Identity Manager. My goal is to securely authenticate IoT devices through Keyrock and have them send data to Orion via the IoT Agent.
Setup:
I have configured the necessary FIWARE components as follows:
Orion Context Broker
IoT Agent (JSON)
Keyrock Identity Manager
User and Role Configuration in Keyrock:
Application ID: tutorial-dckr-site-0000-xpresswebapp
IoT Agent ID: iot_sensor_00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
User: alice-the-admin@test.com with the role entity-reader which has permission to GET /v2/entities/*.
I am encountering two different errors depending on the authentication method used:
1.after Using OAuth2 Token:
curl -X POST 'http://ramona-iot.com:3005/oauth2/token' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d 'grant_type=password&username=alice-the-admin@test.com&password=<alice-password>&client_id=<application-id>&client_secret=<application-secret>

and Request to IoT Agent:
curl -X GET \   'http://ramona-iot.com:1027/v2/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:Temp:003?options=keyValues' \   -H 'Fiware-Service: openiot' \   -H 'Fiware-ServicePath: /' \   -H 'X-Auth-Token: <new-access-token>
I get this Error:
{   "type": "urn:dx:as:UnauthorizedEndpoint",   "title": "Unauthorized",   "detail": "Domain not Found" }
2.after Using /v1/auth/tokens
Request for token:
curl -iX POST 'http://ramona-iot.com:3005/v1/auth/tokens' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"name": "alice-the-admin@test.com","password": "test"}

and Request to IoT Agent:
curl -X GET 'http://ramona-iot.com:1027/v2/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:Temp:003?options=keyValues' -H 'Fiware-Service: openiot' -H 'Fiware-ServicePath: /' -H 'X-Auth-Token: <new-auth-token>

I get this Error:
{   "type": "urn:dx:as:InvalidAuthenticationToken",   "title": "Unauthorized",   "detail": "User not authorized in the application" }
What might be causing the "Domain not Found" error when using OAuth2 tokens? How can I resolve the "User not authorized in the application" error when using /v1/auth/tokens? Are there any additional configurations or steps needed to correctly set up the IoT Agent with Keyrock for OAuth2 authentication?
I also checked the headers Fiware-Service and Fiware-ServicePath in the request.

The error:
{
    "type": "urn:dx:as:InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "title": "Unauthorized",   
    "detail": "User not authorized in the application" 
}

Can be found within the PEP-Proxy code here - this indicates that you have configured your system to use Authzforce, but have not created any policies for the domain.
If you are using Authzforce, you need to set the following variables in Keyrock:
      - IDM_PDP_LEVEL=advanced
      - IDM_AUTHZFORCE_ENABLED=true
      - IDM_AUTHZFORCE_HOST=authzforce
      - IDM_AUTHZFORCE_PORT=${AUTHZFORCE_PORT}

and the following variables in the PEP Proxy:
      - PEP_PROXY_PDP=authzforce
      - PEP_PROXY_AUTH_ENABLED=true
      - PEP_PROXY_MAGIC_KEY=1234
      - PEP_PROXY_AZF_PROTOCOL=http
      - PEP_PROXY_AZF_HOST=authzforce
      - PEP_PROXY_AZF_PORT=${AUTHZFORCE_PORT}


Working example here
If you are not using Authzforce, you need to configure your Keyrock and PEP-Proxy differently. The main parameters are as shown:
      - IDM_PDP_LEVEL=basic
      - IDM_AUTHZFORCE_ENABLED=false

      - PEP_PROXY_PDP=idm

Working example here

now when I try to provision a sensor, I get this error :
{
"name": "WRONG_SYNTAX",
"message": "Wrong syntax in request: Errors found validating request."
}
the heasers are as follow : fiware-service = openiot, fiware-servicepath=/, Accept= application/json

the payload is :
{
"devices": [
{
"device_id":   "temp003",
"entity_name": "urn:ngsi-ld:Temp:003",
"entity_type": "Temp",
"timezone":    "Europe/Berlin",
"attributes": [
{"object_id": "t", "name": "temperature", "type": "Text"},
{"object_id": "e", "name": "event", "type": "Text"}
],
"static_attributes": [
{"name": "refroom", "type": "Relationship", "value": "urn:ngsi-ld:Room:001"}
]
}
]
}
